# PyCharm-style docstring containing code with `>>>`

Tags: python, pycharm, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I just figured out that PyCharm supports a docstring with code prefixed by `>>>` like this:

```
def foo(x):
  """
  Use it like:

  >>> foo(42)
  """
  print(x)
```

PyCharm then even applies the usual code highlighting on this.

I tried to find any documentation on this syntax. It doesn't seem to be part of reStructuredText. Also Sphinx does not mention this. Was this introduced in some PEP? Or is this PyCharm specific? But I did not find any PyCharm documentation on this.

(It's hard to use Google search for this. I don't know how to call this. "3-times greater sign"?)

Comment: It's three fleches: `>>>`, it's part of the doctest standard. You can right click on it in PyCharm and say "Run Doctest"

Comment: Usually it would be `>>>`, that's the Python REPL prompt https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode and is used by e.g.: https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe @PeterWood actually not. At least not for PyCharm. PyCharm does not handle `>>>` in any special way, but it does handle `>>>>`. So maybe it is PyCharm specific? Or does PyCharm takes this over from somewhere?

Comment: I'm stood in front of it now (v2021.2.2 Pro), and it does - as long as there are _at least_ three `>`, it gets formatted as code. As suggested above you can run it as a doctest. With `>>>` it fails because you don't show the output (`Expected nothing Got: 42`), with `>>>>` it fails because that's not a valid REPL (`ValueError: line 4 of the docstring for foo lacks blank after >>>: '>>>> foo(42)'`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh I'm sorry. That is strange. You are right. I tested this before, but somehow I must have done sth differently. Also when I browse documentation from external libs (e.g. PyTorch) which use `>>>`, PyCharm does not correctly format it. But maybe just because they are external.

Comment: You can just put your comment into an answer, and then I can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments have answered the question. I'm just putting it here for completeness:

It's three fleshes (`>>>`).

It's used for [doc test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html).

In PyCharm, when you rightclick it, it allows you to `Run Doctest`.

The syntax probably comes from the [Python interactive shell](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode).